# Need to find out the number of files the person has include with interrelated tables

Tags: sql-server

I need to find out the total number of Files that the person has, it must include the files that belongs to the note which belongs to the person as well.

The person can have mulitple Files and person can have multiple notes, each note can have multiple files.

Best if this can be done in 1 query because this will be part of the bigger dynamic query.

[image]

Comment: What are the possible values for `OwnerTypeID`?

Comment: Can the same be attached to a person _and_ a note of that person? If so do you want to count it once or twice?

Comment: the file can only be attached to person or the note but not both at the same time.

Comment: – Felix Pamittan    you example is fine. i will merge it into the bigger sql and see. Thank you for your reply btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably do this with `JOIN`s and `UNION` coupled with aggregate functions `COUNT` and `SUM`:

```
SELECT
    t.PersonID, FileCount = SUM(cnt)
FROM (
    SELECT
        p.PersonID, cnt = COUNT(f.FileID)
    FROM Person p
    LEFT JOIN Note n
        ON n.PersonID = p.PersonID
    LEFT JOIN [File] f
        ON f.OwnerID = n.NoteID
        AND f.OwnerTypeID = 'Note'
    GROUP BY p.PersonID

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        p.PersonID, cnt = COUNT(f.FileID)
    FROM Person p
    LEFT JOIN [File] f
        ON f.OwnerID = p.PersonID
        AND f.OwnerTypeID = 'Person'
    GROUP BY p.PersonID
)t
GROUP BY t.PersonID
```

The idea is to count first the number of `File`s from under the `Notes` of a `Person` and then count the number of `File`s that are directly under a `Person`. Then simply add the results.

Comment: I have tested it, it need to have the "group by p.personID" in each of the sub query for this to work, else it will through exception when you trying to execute it.

Comment: @Terry, yes. Sorry about that.